# XmlReader how to do it from memory and not disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing

I'm using `XmlReader ProductDoc = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);` and apparently it's taking down the server because it is reading from the disk everytime a user using the search tool.

1. is it true that with every call to the XmlReader there is a call to the disk memory?
2. if so, how can I do this from server memory instead of disk memory

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You cannot read XML from disk without reading the disk.  Use a profiler to find the actual problem.

Comment: what is wrong with your server? why does simple fs io cause it to go down?

Comment: @SLaks, yes, of course you have to read it into memory from the disk, but I don't want that to be done every time the xml is needed. The xml is HUGE

Comment: @animaonline, it's not the server... there is also another aspect that could be taking the server down, this is just one

Comment: the xml files (3 in total) end up being about 2.5 MB and have about 4.8k entries at the root

Comment: I edited the two questions to make more sense :). I did type this in a hurry. Thank you everyone for your quick responses

Comment: 2.5MB is nothing.  Huge is 10GB

Comment: The forward-only XmlReader API (assuming you're using it correctly) is likely to be faster than reading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Even if multiple users hit it? The web tool gets 5k hits a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, your code will read from disk.
2. It sounds like you need to put the data in the cache on the server. This would involve reading the document as an XDocument or just the raw data, and putting it into `Page.Cache`.

Comment: This is more like what I'm thinking. would this work for all user's sessions?

Comment: Page.Cache is a global cache that will be shared between users. The purpose of it is to share data that is expensive to fetch.

Comment: Thank you. I think we are doing something similar in vb.net on the site.

Answer (score 1):

> is this true?

Well we've *no idea* whether that's what's taking down your server. But yes, it will read it from disk each time, at least notionally - I'd expect the file system to cache the file if it's being read a lot though.

> how can I do this from server memory instead of disk memory

If you mean "from memory rather than from disk" and *if* it's always the same path, then I suggest you just load the document into memory once, e.g.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

... and then reuse that in all requests. So long as you're *only* reading from it, it should be fine. You can create a new reader from the document if you want, or just use `XDocument` directly (which is likely to be simpler). You can load the `XDocument` from an `XmlReader` if you want, as an alternative.

Comment: would `XDocument.Load(path);` be a one time for all users's sessions? or would this occur for all sessions one at a time. I'm thinking caching may be what I need so it will work for all user's sessions

Comment: @Jimmmy: It would entirely depend on where you did it. You would basically want to make it global data - you could load it on application start-up. You should read up on the ASP.NET application and page lifecycle for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
XmlReader.Create(Stream)
```

overload. Then use FileStream to read the contents of the file into a MemoryStream (ONLY ONCE!), then kill of the FileStream and just use the MemoryStream.

Just remember to set the position of the stream to 0 each time you create the XmlReader with it and this means only 1 XmlReader can read from it at one time.

If you're running a webserver (asp.net) you'll need to cache the MemoryStream (Page.Cache). Or if the memory footprint isn't too horrific you can just cache it on a per user basis in Session. In Session you also wouldn't have to worry about multiple reader access too.